# Why isn't my setState working correctly? I want to add a div element onClick

Tags: reactjs

I want to setsState to make it re-render. Because if i click on one on the button, it doesnt change color until the second click.

```
import React from 'react';

  class SessionForms extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {colorRed: 0};
      this.loginRed = this.loginRed.bind(this);
      this.signupRed = this.signupRed.bind(this);
  }

  loginRed(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({colorRed: 1})
    this.props.openModal('login');
    const login = document.getElementById("session-button-login");
    const signup = document.getElementById("session-button-signup");

    login.classList.add("red-button");
    signup.classList.add("gray");
  }

  signupRed(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({colorRed: 2})
    this.props.openModal('signup')
    const login = document.getElementById("session-button-login");
    const signup = document.getElementById("session-button-signup");

    signup.classList.add("red-button");
    login.classList.add("gray");

  }


  render() {

    return (
      <div className='session'>
        <div>
          <button className='session-close'
                  onClick={() => this.props.closeModal()} 
          >X</button>
        </div>
        <div className='session-type'>
          <div></div>

          <button
            className='session-type-button'
            id='session-button-login'
            onClick={this.loginRed}>
            LOG IN
          </button>

          <button
            className='session-type-button'
            id='session-button-signup'
            onClick={this.signupRed}>
            JOIN
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default SessionForms;
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?. and why are you using javascript instead of reactjs syntax for forms?

Comment: I think you have to use componentDidUpdate() for the changes.

Answer (score 0):

`setState()` does asynchronous operation. You can call a function after the state value has updated.

```
this.setState({colorRed: 1},()=>{
   console.log(this.state.colorRed});
 })
```

calling callback you can check there value of state is updated.
for better understanding of `setState()`. refer to [React setState is asynchronous!](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3)

Answer (score 0):

replace changing states to the bottom of your methods

```
signupRed(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // this.setState({colorRed: 2}) // <--- from
    this.props.openModal('signup')
    const login = document.getElementById("session-button-login");
    const signup = document.getElementById("session-button-signup");

    signup.classList.add("red-button");
    login.classList.add("gray");

    // it rerenders component after changes above
    this.setState({colorRed: 2}) // <--- to
  }
```

**But as mentioned in comments you should use react approach to work with DOM** (ref, className, style etc.): start with this article: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html